# Why doesn't this Java enum code compile?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum itProfs {  
    private int sal;
    DEVELOPER(30), ANALYST(20); 
    itProfs(int sal){
        this.sal = sal;
    }
    public int getSal(){
        return sal;
    }   
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: What error do you get ? It probably tells you exactly what the reason and the problem is ;)

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't make "itProfs" a class, and make DEVELOPER and ANALYST an enum???????

Comment: Hi guys!! thank you for your advice. I know the error that the enumeration values first. I want to know the inner implementation in Java why. It is not so intuitive to me. Can you explain this deeper (i.e. memory allocations, internals? Btw this is just a sample code because I'm studying java deeper.

Comment: ok thanks. readability, that's the word! this feature in Java is just something new to me. @MeBigFatGuy thanks also!! grammar you said.

Answer (score 5):

You should put enumeration values first.

```
enum itProfs {  
    DEVELOPER(30), ANALYST(20); 
    private int sal;
    itProfs(int sal){
        this.sal = sal;
    }
    public int getSal(){
        return sal;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi guys!! thank you for your quick answer. I know the error that the enumeration values first. I want to know the inner implementation in Java why. It is not so intuitive to me. Can you explain this deeper (i.e. memory allocations, internals?

Comment: just cause. It's how the grammar was defined. They could have done it otherwise, but they didn't

Comment: @BrevisIunius, that has nothing to do with memory allocation. It's just a matter of syntax. I think that the main point is readability here. When someone is looking at enum code the first thing he wants to know is available values. And it would be pretty much uncomfortable to search all the class definition for it.

Comment: ok thanks. readability, that's the word! this feature in Java is just something new to me. @MeBigFatGuy thanks also!! grammar you said.